# Using Rav Ovadia picture from MY

Tags: support

[What Minhag Is This Tefillin Wrapping?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81418/what-minhag-is-this-tefillin-wrapping)

Can I use this picture from your website for my purposes? thanks!

Comment: You can do a Google Image Search to understand where the images come from and what their copyright are. First is from [here](https://www.ynetnews.com/articles/0,7340,L-3476045,00.html) and seems copyrighted, second from [Wiki](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ovadia_Yosef,_2007.jpg) and can be used under the terms described on that page

Answer (score 2):

That post itself says that the picture is taken from Wikipedia, used under a Creative Commons 3.0 license. As the links there indicate, that means that you can use it for any purpose whatsoever, so long as credit is given.

Comment: AFAICT, CC-BY-SA does not prohibit monetization. (Note that the caption you refer to on the original post was added after this question was posted.)